# Flow of data between Angular 2 and Spring

Tags: java, spring, angular

I am about to start my first real project for work (new grad), and I was tasked with creating an internal address book for the company (displaying name, phone extension number, email etc).

My mentor told me that I need to pull the address data from Active Directory.

He also told me that I need to use Angular 2 for the front end, and Spring for the backend. I still need to learn these frameworks, but he realizes this which is precisely why he gave me this task.

However, I am struggling to understand the flow of data between the frameworks.

This is what I am thinking so far https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYrxg.jpg.

[image]

If someone could please explain what is right/wrong with the diagram and perhaps explain how the data would flow in such a project. I would prefer to bother my mentor with more specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a REST service with Spring that returns the data as JSON. You can use a simple POJO on the server side, and the converter for Spring should convert it to JSON. Maybe something like

```
@RestController
public class EmployeesController {

    @Autowired
    private LdapService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{empId}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("empId") Long empId) {
        Employee emp = ldapService.getEmployee(empId);
        return emp;
    }
}
```

With Spring, it should convert the `Employee` object to JSON on the outbound response (given you have the JSON converter configured).

In Angular, just make a simple `Http` request to the endpoint, and you will get back JSON, for which you can convert it to an `Employee` object on the client side. Maybe something like

```
class Employee {
  // employee properties
}

@Injectable()
class EmployeeService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getEmployee(empId: number): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get(`${empBaseUrl}/${empId}`)
      .map(res => res.json() as Employee)
  }
}
```

Here, in the service, you make the `Http` request to the employee endpoint on the server, and get the result back as JSON, for which you convert it to an object with `res.json()` and cast it to `Employee`

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot with my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Converts to useful format" will not happen on its own. You need a Controller layer there. REST Controller to be precise.

AngularJS 2 is built to work easily with REST. You can use Spring MVC to create REST Controllers which can generate JSON Response.

for Example you can have an Endpoint

```
GET /contacts/data
```

which will return

```
[
    {"name":"ABC",
     "email":"someone@abc.com",
     "telephone":"0101010101"
    },
    ...
]
```

The following Spring [documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs) will be a good starting point eventhough it talks about Angularjs 1.